# A bar weighs $2N$ and is $5m$ in length. What is the weight needed to balance the bar?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, moment

A bar weighs $2N$ and is $5m$ in length. What is the weight($M$) needed to balance the bar?

I think I understand that the equation not including the weight of the bar would have $$3*3=(5*1)+(2*M)\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad M=2.$$ I don't understand however how the weight of the bar is distributed? Is that each metre is worth $0.4N$, therefore, the longer side would be $$3*.4= 1.2$$ and to correct this with $M$ you would add another $0.6$ to the $4$ we already had making $M=4.6$? Very dubious about my methodology here however. [image]

Comment: Just consider the centre-of-mass of the beam as the point where the force of gravity acts. With a uniform beam, the centre-of-mass is easy to find. This gives just another torque for the torque equation. Cutting up the beam into sections or considering it as a continuum object isn't necessary, as far as I can see. I don't follow your equation, though. What is `3*3=(5*1)+(2*X)M=4` supposed to mean?

Comment: Hi Steeven, the equation is supposed to show the weight of M, without including the weight of the bar in the equation (sorry made a mistake with m, meant to be 2 not 4). Ok thanks, I think that makes sense. So the weight of the bar acts at 2.5m which is 0.5m from the pivot. Therefore 0.5m*2N=1N anticlokwise and to balance the beam weight we have 1N/2m=0.5N cockwise. So the total weight required at M to balance the beam weight is M=2.5N?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I've not done the math, but that method should work. Thanks, the equation makes sense now :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the bar has a constant mass/length, you can assume that all the weight of the bar will be at the center of mass, which is at the center of the bar (if the mass density is not constant, you will have to calculate the location of the center of gravity of the bar). Now you can just treat the weight of the bar itself just like another force hanging off the bar located at 0.5m from the balance point. So, summing the torques: 
  $$
   (3m)(3N) + (0.5m)(2N) = (1m)(5N) + (2m)(M)\\
   M = 2.5N
  $$